# How can I monitor traffic of an Android app?

Tags: android

I have developed a basic android app- "Hello World" app.
Now I want to intercept it but I can not because it is not using Http/https protocol.
I have tried Burpsuite and fiddler but they are unable to even detect the app.
What is the method to intercept a custom (self-made app)?

Comment: "it is not using Http/https protocol" -- so, what is it using?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But if it would be using any of these protocols, Burpsuite must have detected the app.So I concluded that my app is not using any of these protocols that is why Burpsuite is unable to detect it

Comment: "I don't know" -- by default, an Android app does not do anything with the Internet. If you did not write anything that uses the Internet, and you did not connect to a third-party library that uses the Internet, then your app will not be using the Internet. In fact, if you did not add the `INTERNET` permission to your manifest, your app *cannot* be using the Internet.

Comment: I got it. So there's no way to monitor that app until it's directly or indirectly connected to the Internet?

Comment: I guess that I do not know what you mean by "monitor". The role of Burpsuite, Wireshark, etc. is to monitor network traffic. If your app has no network traffic, then there is nothing to monitor with those tools.

Comment: What I want to do right now is that when I open this "Hello World" app on my mobile phone, my PC should be able to display the plaintext content "Hello World". I think I can not do that using Burpsuite, Fiddler, etc. Can you recommend to me any tool to serve the purpose?

Comment: "my PC should be able to display the plaintext content "Hello World"." -- then you need to write code to do that. "Can you recommend to me any tool to serve the purpose?" -- Android Studio or some other Android app development IDE are typical tools to write Android apps, whether they connect to another computer via TCP/IP, Bluetooth, USB, or some other connectivity option.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it for sure.